# Can use @Ignore field in Constructor for Room database?

Tags: java, android, android-room, pojo, android-database

I have a `room database`.In my `Entity`(PerformanceEntry) I don't want to save one field(String studentName) in table, But i want to access the field in List.

I used `@Ignore` to field ,But in that case i cant use field in constructor too.

I want to know it is there any solution? or i must create field in table?

Note : 
This field is a temporary value and i don't want to save it to the table.

```
@Entity(tableName = "performance")
public class PerformanceEntry {

@ColumnInfo(name = "entry_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int entryId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "class_id")
    private int classId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "class_date")
    private String classDate;
    private boolean absent;
    private boolean delay;
    private int positive;
    private int negative;

    @Ignore
    private String studentName;

    public PerformanceEntry(int entryId, int classId, String studentId, String classDate, boolean absent, boolean delay, int positive, int negative, String studentName) {
    this.entryId = entryId;
    this.classId = classId;
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.classDate = classDate;
    this.absent = absent;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.positive = positive;
    this.negative = negative;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    }
}
```

**error :**

```
error: Cannot find setter for field.
```

Comment: Can u provide the entire error log? The code that u have shared does not need any setter for `studentName`

Comment: have you tried with two constructors with&without "studentName" ?

Comment: yes i tried but doesn't work and show me above error

Answer (score 2):

You can use annotation @Transient instead of @Ignore

Comment: No it's not my answer i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `@PrimaryKey` field below your `@Ignore` field.